# Default locale for ajax request

Tags: symfony

I need to translate my application. I set the prefix up for all my routes.

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix:   /{_locale}
```

It works but I would like to set a default locale. For example, some routes are set to be called by ajax request. It has to work for all locales. For example `/foo/data` is one of my route and is defined by `/{_locale}/foo/data`. I would like to force all routes to have a default locale to force the locale if it's not provided.

Is there a solution for my issue or should I redefine the urls of my ajax requests manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
prefix:   /{_locale, locale: default}
```

Where `default` is your default country